# How can I fix this code to be able to properly record physical mouse movement and then be able to repeat the mouse movement

Tags: python, mouseevent

The code Im trying to make isnt working correctly does anyone know how to fix it or a better way to go about it? I tryed using this code in which I would record the speed of the mouse and try to replicate it over a timeline but it doesnt really work. Tell me if there is anything that is wrong with the code or if there is an objectively better way to go about this:

```
import time
import sys
from pynput import keyboard, mouse

recorded_input = []
recording = False
start_time = None

mouse_controller = mouse.Controller()


def on_key_press(key):
    global recording, recorded_input, start_time
    if key == keyboard.Key.up:
        if recording:
            recording = False
            start_time = None
        else:
            if recorded_input:
                recorded_input.clear()
            recording = True
            start_time = time.time()
    elif key == keyboard.Key.down:
        execute_recorded_input()
    elif key == keyboard.Key.right:
        stop_program()
        return False  


def on_move(x, y):
    global recording, start_time
    if recording:
        current_time = time.time()
        if start_time is not None:
            elapsed_time = current_time - start_time
            recorded_input.append({'event': 'move', 'x': x, 'y': y, 'timestamp': elapsed_time})


def execute_recorded_input():
    current_x, current_y = mouse_controller.position
    for i, event in enumerate(recorded_input):
        if event['event'] == 'move':
            if i < len(recorded_input) - 1:
                next_event = recorded_input[i + 1]
                duration = next_event['timestamp'] - event['timestamp']
                delta_x = next_event['x'] - event['x']
                delta_y = next_event['y'] - event['y']
                speed_x = delta_x / duration
                speed_y = delta_y / duration
                start_time = time.time()
                while time.time() - start_time < duration:
                    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
                    move_x = current_x + int(speed_x * elapsed_time)
                    move_y = current_y + int(speed_y * elapsed_time)
                    mouse_controller.position = (move_x, move_y)
                    time.sleep(0.01) 

def stop_program():
    print("Program stopped")
    sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_key_press) as key_listener:
        with mouse.Listener(on_move=on_move) as mouse_listener:
            key_listener.join()
            mouse_listener.join()
```